# Which web server can return this page with empty html tags ? Cloudflare / Nginx / Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using a monitoring tool that constantly checks server status, and sometimes it gets this empty tags reply. The monitoring service doesn't give me more info, like status code.

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I remember I seen that page before but I cannot remember which one of these 3 does that:

- Cloudflare (error / rate limiting)
- Nginx (error)
- Apache (error, PHP error)

Each request goes trough all 3 enviroments and I cannot find which one ocasionally sends this reply.

Maybe someone remembers seeing this on their servers.

Comment: You should check the HTTP headers for more information.

Comment: The only way is to capture network packets on the components (nginx/Apache at least) and then analyze. Might be caused by PHP improperly handled errors, but can also be from elsewhere.